# When color inkjet cartridge is low copies come out shaded and faded, even though there's plenty of black ink,

Tags: printer, ink, copy

Note that I'm asking about COPYING, not printing.

I'm making copies on an HP Envy 5643, and it says the color cartridge is low. Even though I'm making black & white copies, and there's plenty of black ink, the copies start coming out blue, green, red...whatever's left in the color cartridge, and get fainter and fainter.

I know there are hacks to force PRINTING from the black cartridge. Are there any to force COPYING?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Features to print Black Only.

https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05078948

> On the properties window, click the Paper/Quality or Features tab,
> depending on your software. To print using only the black ink
> cartridge, change one of the following settings depending on what
> displays. Click Advanced, click Print in Grayscale, and then select
> Black Ink Only.

Please note the warning:

> Some HP printers must have some ink of each color available to print.
> For these types of printers, the ink is used for periodic servicing
> tasks. This helps to prevent issues such as printhead clogs and poor
> print quality. **There is no way to bypass this feature.**

It is probably best and easiest in the long run to replace the color cartridges to ensure proper performance.